# mutableCopy memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

Can anyone shed some light as to why this use of mutableCopy is leaking memory?

```
- (id)objectInListAtIndex:(unsigned)theIndex {
       NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"noteNumber"  ascending:YES] autorelease];
       [list sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
       NSMutableArray *theArray = [list mutableCopy];
       NSDictionary *theDict = [theArray objectAtIndex:theIndex];
       return theDict;
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Because `mutableCopy` returns a retained object, and you never release `theArray`.

Copy methods always return a retained object which the caller is responsible for releasing. This is also detailed in the [API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSMutableCopying/mutableCopyWithZone%3a) and the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW3).